# Errno 30 and 33 while installing Ubuntu 12.10 from burned DVD

Tags: system-installation, 12.10

I believe I have tried every trick in the book, but Ubuntu just won't install. Windows has no issue with it.

I burned a DVD of Ubuntu 12.10 and it has passed all checks, but I keep getting different errors while installing. Mainly while "Creating the Partition in dev" and sometimes during "Copying files". The errors are:

```
Errno 30, Errno 33,
Installer crashed, failed to create partition etc...
```

I have Intel core 2 duo 2.66Ghz, 4GB RAM and an ASrock motherboard.
I really want to install Ubuntu 12.10 and 12.10 only!

Is 32-bit or 64-bit better suited to my machine? I have burned a 32-bit version.

By "Windows has no issue with it", I mean that it installs perfectly  with no errors during installation.

I do not know about "md5sum"; it has been checked with the tool in the DVD itself.  Also, when I tried to boot it from the USB using [LiLi](https://www.linuxliveusb.com/), it passes its checks.

Also during installation, I get IO Error and stuff like that written  on the command line box during installation, but it still proceeds further until I get a dialogue box with an error on it.

Comment: 32 bit is fine.  By "passed all checks" does this include comparing the md5sum of the downloaded iso with it's published correct value?

Comment: Does the CD boot "Live"? I do not understand <snip>Windows has no issue with it..... Plus Fabricator's question is VERY important.

Answer (score 0):

its either DVD drive or HDD is not working properly

check all the cords connecting those chups + check S.M.A.R.T.

Answer (score 0):

you may need to correctly manage hard drive.Create  / primiry ex4 partition for about 20 gigs, swap partition with the size of double amount of your ram  and /home partition with lots of space cause there will be all you download. http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2011/05/04/manual-disk-partitioning-guide-for-ubuntu-11-04/